# How to show this inequality holds?

Tags: calculus, integration, monotone-functions

Consider$$A_{i}=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(p-(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{w+1}}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right)\right]\right) \cdot \prod_{j\neq i}^m\left[p+(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{j}^2}{2}\right)\right]dwdp,$$ where $0 \le w \le 1$, $0 \le p \le 1$ and $x_i \in (0,\infty)\ \forall i = 1, \dots, m$. Note that, $A_{i}$ is expected value and can get values between $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

And, suppose $x_{i}$'s are ordered such that $x_{1}<x_{2}<...<x_{m}$.

I have been trying to show that $A_{m}<A_{m-1}<...<A_{1}$,but I could not show it analytically. Numerically, I have shown that $A_{m}<A_{m-1}<...<A_{1}$ by generating some $x_{i}$'s. Could anyone help me to show it? Thanks in advance.

I have tried to show it for $m=2$, and its clear that $A_{1}>A_{2}$ when $$p>(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{w+1}}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)$$ since $$p-(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{w+1}}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)\tag{*}$$ is positive. But I couldn't show it when $$p<(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{w+1}}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)$$ since $(*)$ is negative, and in this case showing that $A_{1}>A_{2}$ is being more complicated for me.

Comment: Would help to know where this came from. Presumably it's the probability of something.

Comment: Okay....  what event?

Comment: Also is it the case that the parens are a bit misleading? the term (1-p)(sqrt(1-w)exp(wxi/)) is being multiplied against the second expression, not the full grouping?

Comment: yes this term is being multiplied against the second expression not the full grouping.I think now it looks better.the question is too long, I have computed this probailities and now just wondering if I can order them as I stated above.thanks @djechlin

Comment: Okay, how I'm actually working on this is by trying to figure out what probability event this is modeling. If you're not going to post information on that after I keep asking, I'm not going to work on this.

Comment: I am doing Bayesian model selection and this is the posterior probability of the model i. @djechlin

Comment: Can you show it for $m=2$?

Comment: @martycohen Sorry for late response,I haven't had internet access for 2 days and couldn't see your question.
I tried to show it for $m=2$, and its clear that $A_{2}<A_{1}$ when $p>(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)$ since $p-(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)$ is positive.But I couldn't show it when $p<(1-p)\sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(\frac{wx_{i}^2}{2}\right)\left[1-\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right]\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_j(w)= \sqrt{1-w}\exp\left(w\dfrac{x_j^2}2\right),$ then $f'_j(w)=\left(-\dfrac1{2\sqrt{1-w}}+\sqrt{1-w}\dfrac{x_j^2}2\right)\exp\left(w\dfrac{x_j^2}2\right).$
It is maximal when $f'_j(w)=0$ ie at $x_j^2 = \dfrac1{1-w},$
$$f_j(w) \leq f(w),\quad \text{ where}\quad f(w) = \sqrt{1-w}\exp\dfrac w{2(1-w)}.$$
Derivation of $f(w)$ is:$\quad f'(w)=\left(-\dfrac1{2\sqrt{1-w}} +\dfrac{\sqrt{1-w}}{2(1-w)^2}\right)\exp\dfrac w{2(1-w)},$
$$f'(w)=\dfrac w{2(1-w)^2}f(w).$$
$f(w)$ has minimum when $$w = 0,\quad f_{min}(w) = f(0) = 1,$$ and singularity when
$$w\to1,\quad \lim\limits_{w\to 1}f(w) = \infty.$$
On the other hand, function $$g_i(w)=\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right)$$ has maximum at $w\in[0,1]$ when $w=0$, ie $$\max\limits_{w\in[0,1]}\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right) = 1.$$
So
$$A_{i} \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(p-(1-p)\min_wf_i(w)\left[1-\frac{1}{w+1}\exp\left(\frac{-w^2x_{i}^2}{2(w+1)}\right)\right]\right) \cdot \prod_{j\neq i}^m (p+(1-p)f(w))dwdp =$$$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 p(p+(1-p)f(w))^{m-1}dwdp \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 pf^{m-1}(w))dwdp = \dfrac12\int_0^1 f^{m-1}(w)dw.$$
$$\boxed{A_{i} \leq \dfrac12\int_0^1 f^{m-1}(w)dw}$$

**On the main issue.**

$$A_i-A_j = \int_0^1\int_0^1(((p-(1-p)f_i(w)(1-g_i(w))((p+(1-p)f_j(w))- $$$$((p-(1-p)f_j(w)(1-g_j(w))((p+(1-p)f_i(w)))\cdot\prod_{k\neq i,\,k\neq j}^m (p+(1-p)f_k(w))dwdp = $$$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1(1-p)(p(f_i(w)g_i(w))-f_j(w)g_j(w)) + (1-p)f_i(w)f_j(w)(g_i(w)-g_j(w)))\cdot \prod_{k\neq i,\,k\neq j}^m (p+(1-p)f_k(w))dwdp = $$$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1(1-p)(p(h_i(w)-h_j(w)) + (1-p)f_i(w)f_j(w)(g_i(w)-g_j(w)))\cdot \prod_{k\neq i,\,k\neq j}^m (p+(1-p)f_k(w))dwdp, $$ 
where $h_i(w) = f_i(w)\cdot g_i(w).$

Considering this formula with the functions
$$f(w,t) = \sqrt{1-w}\exp wt,\quad g(w,t) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1+w}}\exp\left(-\dfrac{w^2t}{w+1}\right),\quad h(w,t) = f(w,t)g(w,t) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-w}{1+w}}\exp\dfrac{wt}{w+1}$$ when $\dfrac{x_j^2}2\to \dfrac{x_i^2}2 = t,$ we can change differences under the integral to according derivations:
$$\dfrac{h_i(w)-h_j(w)}{t_i-t_j}\to\dfrac{dh}{dt} = \dfrac w{w+1}h(w,t),$$
$$f_i(w)f_j(w)\dfrac{g_i(w)-g_j(w)}{t_i-t_j}\to f^2(w,t)\dfrac{dg}{dt} = -\dfrac{w^2}{w+1}f(w,t)^2g(w,t) = -\dfrac{w^2}{w+1}f(w,t)h(w,t) = -wf(w,t)\dfrac{dh}{dt}.$$
So
$$A_i-A_j \to \dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1(1-p)(p-(1-p)wf(w,t))\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,\prod_{k\neq i,\,k\neq j}^m (p+(1-p)f_k(w))\,dwdp.$$
When $m=2$:
$$A_i-A_j \to \dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1(1-p)(p-(1-p)wf(w,t))\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dwdp = {\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1((p-p^2)-(1-p)^2w \sqrt{1-w}\exp(wt))\dfrac{w}{1+w}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-w}{1+w}}\exp\left(\dfrac{w}{w+1}t\right)\,dwdp}= {\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}{12}\int\limits_0^1(1-2w \sqrt{1-w}\exp(wt))\dfrac{w}{1+w}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-w}{1+w}}\exp\left(\dfrac{w}{w+1}t\right)\,dw}.$$

Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%281-2w+%5Csqrt%7B1-w%7D%5Cexp%280.84w%29%29%5Cdfrac%7Bw%7D%7B1%2Bw%7D%5Csqrt%7B%5Cdfrac%7B1-w%7D%7B1%2Bw%7D%7D%5Cexp%5Cleft%28%5Cdfrac%7B0.84w%7D%7Bw%2B1%7D%5Cright%29%5C%2Cdw) program, we can see that this expression is greater than $0$ when $t\leq 0.83$ and less than $0$ when $t\geq 0.84$.

When $m=3$:
$$A_i-A_j \to \dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1(1-p)(p-(1-p)wf(w,t))(p+(1-p)f(w,t_1))\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dwdp = \dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^ 1(p^2(1-p) - p(1-p)^2wf(w,t) + p(1-p)^2f(w,t))+(1-p)^3wf(w,t)f(w,t_1))\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dwdp = $$$$\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}2\int\limits_0^ 1\left(\dfrac1{12} - \dfrac7{12}wf(w,t) + \dfrac7{12}f(w,t_1)-\dfrac14wf(w,t)f(w,t_1)\right)\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dw = $$$$\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}{72}\int\limits_0^ 1(6 - 21wf(w,t) + 21f(w,t_1)-9wf(w,t)f(w,t_1))\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dw = $$$$\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}{72}\int\limits_0^1((7 - 3wf(w,t))(7 + 3f(w,t_1))-43)\dfrac{dh}{dt}\,dw = $$$$\dfrac{x_i^2-x_j^2}{72}\int\limits_0^1((7 - 3w\sqrt{1-w}\exp(wt))(7 + 3\sqrt{1-w}\exp(wt_1))-43)\dfrac{w}{1+w}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-w}{1+w}}\exp\left(\dfrac{w}{w+1}t\right)\,dw.$$

Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%28-31%2B%287-3%5Csqrt%7B1-w%7Dw%5Cexp%284w%29%29%287-3%5Csqrt%7B1-w%7D%5Cexp%282.5w%29%29%29%5Cdfrac%7Bw%7D%7B1%2Bw%7D%5Csqrt%7B%5Cdfrac%7B1-w%7D%7B1%2Bw%7D%7D%5Cexp%28%5Cdfrac%7B4w%7D%7Bw%2B1%7D%29dw) program at $t=4$, we can see that expression is greater than $0$ when $t_1\geq 2.8$ and less than $0$ when $t_1\leq 2.7$.

So the hypothesis about $A_i<A_j$ is wrong.

Comment: Could you explain it by giving more details if its possible?Since I am not very familiar with "notation O",I could not understand what you have done.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur Now everything is clear and simple)

Comment: Thanks for your time but what you have tried to show is not the answer of my question. And, also you concluded A_{i} <=1/2 which is not true because you made a mistake in the last second line.I need to show that A_{m}<A_{m-1}<...<A_{1} as I indicated above.thanks though.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur About $A_m \leq A_{m-1} \leq \dots \leq A_1:$ there is a consequence of $f_j(w) \leq f(w) \leq 1$.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur I don't see a mistake. What do you mean?

Comment: sorry there is no mistake in the last second line, I made mistake when I was following what you did.

Comment: Jimmy Dur So, there is no manifest error. But something was wrong?

Comment: I cant see how what you showed implies that $A_{m}<A_{m-1}<...<A_{1}$, let me try to understand it.Another thing is that when I numerically computed $A_{i}$'s, it gets values between $0$ and infinity, its not bounded with $1/2$ as you showed.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur I have to think

Comment: take your time! thanks again for your effort.and I have just realized that the function $f(w)$ that you defined is mostly greater than $1$ for most of the values of w, it not bounded with 1.

Comment: Yuri, yesterday someone downvoted an answer given by me to a similar question posted by the OP some time ago, despite being correct. I have strong rasons to suspect that it was you, it's not necessary to detail them here. This is called "revenge vote", and it is not nice to do. Anyway, I have plenty of reputation points, so I won't mind, but if you keep doing this you might get banned by the moderators. Why have I downvoted this answer of yours? Because, as the OP himself notes, it does not answer the asked question, so don't feel offended.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov I am not clear about how this last inequality implies the desired result? and another thing is that how we can write this $\prod_{j\neq i}^m (p+(1-p)f(w))=f^{m-1}(w)$?I have been trying to figure out these questions but I couldn't and that is why I am asking you.Thanks.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur $f(w)\geq 1$, so it's valid,

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov oh okay,thats part is clear now.but I still cant see how ${A_{i} \leq \dfrac12\int_0^1 f^{m-1}(w)dw}$ implies $A_{m}<A_{m-1}<...<A_{1}$.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov you said 'It leaves no doubt that the difference $A_{i}-A_{j}$ may receive both positive and negative values when $x_{j}<x_{i}$'.so, how can we can say that $A_{i}<A_{j}$ when $x_{j}<x_{i}$?Could you please little bit explain your last two sentences?I am sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: @AlexM. sorry for bothering you.I dont know if is it okay to ask you to review the above answer quickly if you dont mind.Since I am not clear with the answer, I would like to get some ideas from other person who has more knowledge in math and familiar with this kind of problems.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur The topic is complicated, questions are unavoidable (okay). Formula on Wolfram Alpha up to the averaging of probabilities and any coefficient corresponds to the case $m = 2$. This formula is derived under the assumption that $X_i$ and $X_j$ minimally different from each other. I specifically asked in the formula $t = \dfrac{X^2}2 = 2$, because with this value this difference starts a sharp increase in favor of the $X_j$. Change $t=2$ to $t=5$ to verify that.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov But for $t<1.95$, the difference $A_{i}-A_{j}$>0 and this contradicts with what we wanted to show, right?So we cant say that $A_{i}<A_{j}$ when $x_{i}>x_{j}$ for any $x_{j}>0$.how can we say that what you showed answers the main question? I dont know if I am missing something.:/

Comment: @JimmyDur: The answer can be split in three parts: the first one extends from the beginning down to *"On the main issue"* and, as commented previously, has no connection with your question; the seond part goes from there down to *"Considering this formula with the functions"* and is correct, but doesn't prove anything; the last part is supposed to be the proof, but is wrong *at least* because $g(w,t)$ should have been $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt {1+w}} \exp \left( -\dfrac {w^2 t} {2(w+1)} \right)$ (i.e. a square root and a factor of $2$ in a denominator are missing). I haven't looked for other mistakes.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur Yes, it refuted the idea that the difference is any certain sign.

Comment: @Alex M.  That's significant moment, thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy Dur I took into account Alex M.  comments, the findings of previous

Comment: @AlexM.Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks a lot for your help and effort! you got the bounties for your help.I have not accepted the answer yet, but will do it after reviewing the answer carefully.Thanks again!

Comment: @Jimmy Dur My present is $m=3$ case. Happy New Year!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov thanks a lot, happy new year,too.